# exception in using annotation in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

guys i am newbie in hibernate  .. i am trying to use annotation in hibernate but it gives me an exception .. here is my code ..  any suggestions .. thanks in advance

in hibernate.cfg.xml

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>

<!-- Related to the connection START -->
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver </property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb </property>
<property name="connection.user">root </property>
<property name="connection.password">root</property>
<!-- Related to the connection END -->

<!-- Related to hibernate properties START -->
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="dialet">org.hibernate.dialet.MYSQLDialet</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
<!-- Related to hibernate properties END-->

<!-- Related to mapping START-->
<mapping resource="user.hbm.xml" />
<!-- Related to the mapping END -->

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

DataProvider.java

```java
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="dataprovider")
public class DataProvider {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private int user_id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String user_name;
    @Column(name="description")
    private String user_desc;


    public int getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }
    public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }
    public String getUser_name() {
        return user_name;
    }
    public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
        this.user_name = user_name;
    }
    public String getUser_desc() {
        return user_desc;
    }
    public void setUser_desc(String user_desc) {
        this.user_desc = user_desc;
    }


}
```

in InsertData.java

```java
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class InsertData {
    private static SessionFactory factory;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        factory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(DataProvider.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();
        new InsertData().insertInfo();

    }

    public void insertInfo() {
        Session session = factory.openSession();

        DataProvider provider = new DataProvider();
        provider.setUser_id(121);
        provider.setUser_name("name");
        provider.setUser_desc("desc");

        Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(provider);
        System.out.println("Object Saved");

        tr.commit();
        session.close();
        factory.close();

    }

}
```

the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:12)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.<clinit>(AnnotationConfiguration.java:78)
    at InsertData.main(InsertData.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
```

Comment: exception says `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory`. Include `slf4j` jar and try.

Answer (score 0):

All dependencies required by Hibernate are not loaded, if you use maven all jars referenced are automatically loaded in the Application classpath.

As your error is clearly saying , you are missing a reference to the sl4j jar.

https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiBxfuDrM_LAhWCVI4KHU2uBZYQFghAMAY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmvnrepository.com%2Fartifact%2Forg.slf4j%2Fslf4j-api&usg=AFQjCNFZmEX-pLO1rqWxEyCRGohyjvgEFw

Answer (score 0):

The exception is quite clear: the class `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory` is required by Hibernate, but was not found. You need to add the corresponding Library to your classpath, i.e. you need an slf4j.jar in addition to hibernate.jar.